# Are PHP requests encrypted over SSL

Tags: php, ssl, parameters, header

I am creating a simple PHP application which uses **JQuery** and **AJAX** to call (GET method) a PHP script with some parameters; `username` and `password`. The application uses SSL.

When tracing the request in Google Chrome Developer tools, I see the following request URL:

> https://application.com/php/login.php?username=John&password=Simple1234

I used *WireShark* to make sure the parameters are encrypted when sending the request, and I don't see any obvious request-headers.

Just to be a 100% sure. Does SSL also encrypt parameters which are included in the header and am I doing this the right way? I found some duplicate questions about this topic, but none of them had a specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it is a bad idea to use $_GET for such sensitiv data.

- This data would be saved in the server logs
- This data would be saved in the browser cache
- Even Screenshots taken while the login process could contain this data

Also even if the data is encrypted it is still "availble" and could be decrypted. 
Use $_POST instead.

This article will show the risks:

https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, I changed the GET request for the POST method and read the article you included. Learned much from your answer, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is PHP or AJAX does not matter here.

The only thing that matters is the URL: is it `https://` or `http://`?

If it is `https://` since it means it is HTTPS(!) which means in summary HTTP inside TLS (SSL is dead since 20 years, its successor is TLS).

TLS encrypts everything (it does other things too but here we discuss only confidentiality needs), **if implemented and configured correctly** (I want to emphasize that because it is not a silver bullet, putting a sticker "TLS" is not enough, for example there is the whole issue of certificates verification, as authentication may be deemed more important that confidentiality in fact, because what do you gain if you encrypt everything towards an endpoint you are not 100% sure it is the valid one?)

What you see in the URL is part of the HTTP protocol. The URL will be inside the HTTP stream as `GET /php/login.php?...`, just before other headers. Same if using other HTTP methods. Since it is inside HTTP, it is inside TLS, hence encrypted.

The only thing visible by a passive monitor will be the domain name (both for DNS queries before the HTTPS connection - DNS over HTTPS/TLS solves that - and because of the SNI extension at the beginning of the TLS handshake - and encrypted SNI, still being designed, will solve that).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I marked Thorsten's answer as the accepted answer because he gave me a way to improve the security as well as answering the question.